# Как использовать шаблоны Pug?

Tags: pug

Друзья, всем доброго времени суток.

Я некоторое время назад учился веб-разработке и сейчас настало время освежить мои знания. Вообщем у меня не получается скомпилировать html из двух файлов - layout.pug и header.pug. Видимо, я в упор не вижу свою ошибку. Можете подсказать что не так?
Код прилагаю

```html
doctype html
head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    meta(name='format-detection' content='telephone=no')
    //link(rel ='stylesheet' href='css/normalize.css')
    //link(rel ='stylesheet' href='../assets/css/main.css')
    
    //link(rel='shortcut icon' href='img/favicon.ico')
    //<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--title Разработка сайтов-->
body
  block header
```

```html
extends ./layout/
block header
  nav
```

Результирующий HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <!--link(rel ='stylesheet' href='css/normalize.css')-->
  <!--link(rel ='stylesheet' href='../assets/css/main.css')-->
  <!--link(rel='shortcut icon' href='img/favicon.ico')-->
  <!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <!--title Разработка сайтов-->
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

Структура проекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все работает как положено. что не так? вы походу компилируете в html шаблон layout, и ожидаете что он откомпилирует второй шаблон

Comment: если вы хотите вставить один шаблон в другой, то для этого надо использовать функцию include а не extends. А extends - это наследование шаблона с перегрузкой другими блоками.

Comment: А, спасибо больше всем. Действительно, перепутал.